# Rails server status in real time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-server

I have 10 instances running on my linux server, but i don't have any system to know that which server is gone down and which one live in real time, so i can restart the server manually/automatically(if possible?). 
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of process monitoring system.
God is one example. http://godrb.com/